# Islam and stoning

Tags: practical-islam, muslim-practices

For crimes that are major or at least major in the Islamic world they can be punished by stoning/lashing. Lets say someone stole and was supposed to go to prison for X amount of years and they get caught and they get lashed they would do this in the public (or at least thats what Ive seen). This brings shame to them and can bring disgrace to the family and may leave some serious scars so Im a bit put off by this but I guess some would rather do this than go to prison for 20 years or something I dont know. If the sentence is shorter than this is questionable too.

However, stoning is just barbaric to me. The person is literally tortured right before they die. imagine getting your bones shattered and its also done so in front of everyone this can also impact the way others think and probably even kids.  People get stoned for things like adultery and yes some may say that it ruins the family but it isnt the only thing you can do. There can be other punishmetns like giving fees, doing work as payback and jail you could do them all the same time and these are just the ones Ive thought of just now. If stoning is also allowed for adultery imagine all the people that havent been punished yet and how we have to punish them. If its to redeem for the afterlife then theres lots of other ways to do so too.

The idea of stoning just doesnt fit a peaceful religion to me so I was wondering how can stoning be allowed?

Answer (score 1):

Stoning isn't "allowed." It is the prescribed punishment by Allah for the crime of adultery.

It is prescribed because it is the punishment they deserve. There is nothing more to say about it. If you think it is too much, that is your opinion. Allah has a better sense of justice than individual humans.

The Prophet (SAW) said:

> The child is to be attributed to one on whose bed he is born, and for a fornicator there is stoning. ([Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/17/48))

Saying something doesn't fit the concept of a "peaceful religion" is not an escape from anything you dislike. Islam is a religion of justice. Stoning is what adulterers deserve, and Allah prescribed it.

Comment: Would a person still be stoned if he repented and asked for forgiveness  ?

Comment: @TheMadHatter If Zina is proven with the required evidence and about to be punished, repentance wouldn't stop the punishment. Repentance is between them and Allah. Repentance will not stop it anymore than it would stop execution for murder.

Comment: @TheZ but the human interpretation of what a peaceful religions is is what primarily brings the problem of stoning and Im asking because I have doubt. For an adulterer stoning could leave the family without someone to provide the food, and it in and of itself is a gruesome torturous thing. Is there no alternative? A just religion can be just without the need for such violence

Comment: You mean more like "modern liberal" interpretation. For most of human history, no one would blink an eye at such a punishment. In any case, humans have no business deciding over God. The "provide food" argument only works if you think adultery deserves no punishment. You wouldn't use the "provide food" argument to keep a robber out of jail or a murderer. The point is God already told us adultery deserves punishment worse than robbery. It isn't a debate.